# Is it possible to create this animation using particles.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, particles.js

I've been trying to make an animation similar to [this](https://gyazo.com/2a560b0b3b6e6cdf4f3feb520ea8c419) but all I was able to achieve so far using particles.js is [this](https://codepen.io/Eliteware/pen/gOppZXm).

Basically I was unable to make the shapes look like spheres and the interaction element itself is very lacking. So I'm just wondering If I can actually use particles.js for this, or if there's a much better or easier option.

JavaScript:

```
 particlesJS("particles-js", {
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 147,
      density: { enable: true, value_area: 946.9771699587272 }
    },
    color: { value: "#017185" },
    shape: {
      type: "circle",
      stroke: { width: 0, color: "#000000" },
      polygon: { nb_sides: 3 },
      image: { src: "img/github.svg", width: 100, height: 100 }
    },
    opacity: {
      value: 1,
      random: false,
      anim: { enable: false, speed: 1, opacity_min: 0.1, sync: false }
    },
    size: {
      value: 15,
      random: false,
      anim: { enable: false, speed: 40, size_min: 0.1, sync: false }
    },
    line_linked: {
      enable: false,
      distance: 150,
      color: "#ffffff",
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: 1
    },
    move: {
      enable: true,
      speed: 6,
      direction: "none",
      random: false,
      straight: false,
      out_mode: "out",
      bounce: false,
      attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 1200 }
    }
  },
  interactivity: {
    detect_on: "canvas",
    events: {
      onhover: { enable: true, mode: "repulse" },
      onclick: { enable: true, mode: "push" },
      resize: true
    },
    modes: {
      grab: { distance: 400, line_linked: { opacity: 1 } },
      bubble: { distance: 400, size: 40, duration: 2, opacity: 8, speed: 3 },
      repulse: { distance: 200, duration: 0.4 },
      push: { particles_nb: 4 },
      remove: { particles_nb: 2 }
    }
  },
  retina_detect: true
});
var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats();
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
stats.domElement.style.left = "0px";
stats.domElement.style.top = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector(".js-count-particles");
update = function() {
  stats.begin();
  stats.end();
  if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know It's not possible with Particle.js
Check out [Three js](https://threejs.org/) and its amazing features. 
You can detect mouse event on particles such as bellow examples:

[Waves](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_waves.html) 
[Points](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_billboards.html)

Good luck